# Need help formatting output

Tags: powershell, format, output

The below code gives me a count of all folders in a top level file path but I want to display the name of file to the left of output and add a column above the count. For example I want a column header that says "Folder Count".

```
$List = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory "\\whatever\whatever"
foreach ($Folder in $List) 
{ 
    $Count = (Get-ChildItem -Directory $Folder.FullName).Count | write-host 
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory "\\whatever\whatever" |Select Name,@{Name='Folder Count';Expression={@($_ |Get-ChildItem).Count}}`

Comment: Mathias - this script gives me the name of the folder but it gives me a count of all items in the folder including the folder  as well as the files count. I just want a count of the folders in each folder. Thanks

Comment: To count just the subfolders in each folder, add `-Directory` to the second `Get-ChildItem` call in @Mathias' command too.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 and Mathias